# Discord.js is it possible to delete a channel only with "close" (without channeID)?

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

Hey I'm working on a small answer bot. My members can open tickets/channels with an already existing discord bot and in these tickets they write with my bot. Now I wanna do something that they just have to write "delete", without any channelid or name and the channel should get deleted.
I searched for it, but all I found wasn't exactly what I wanted. I tried a little bit around but I just get errors.

This is the code:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");
const prefix = require('discord-prefix');


client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("I am ready!");
});
//if the server doesn't have a set prefix yet
let defaultPrefix = '.';

client.on('message', (message) => {
    
    if (!message.guild) return;

    //get the prefix for the discord server
    let guildPrefix = prefix.getPrefix(message.guild.id);

    
    if (!guildPrefix) guildPrefix = defaultPrefix;

   
    let args = message.content.slice(guildPrefix.length).split(' ');
    if (!message.content.startsWith(guildPrefix)) return;
    
    
    
    
    if (args[0].toLowerCase() === ('ping')) {
        const user = message.author.name;
        return message.reply('pong');
} else

if (args[0].toLowerCase() === ('close') || args[0].toLowerCase() === ('delete') || args[0].toLowerCase() === ('cancel')) {
    
        const channel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === name)
        channel.delete('Deleting the channel')
    .then(deleted => console.log(`Deleted ${deleted.name}`))
    .catch(console.error);
        
    };

});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You could give the Channel a special name. For example
`MEMBERSID-TICKET` and after the User uses the CMD it searches for a channel that includes the `Members ID` and `TICKET`.

Comment: Vielen Dank für deine Antwort. Es klingt sinnvoll, aber ehrlich gesagt habe ich keine Ahnung was ich in dem Code umändern muss, damit das funktioniert. Ich habe gegooglet, aber nicht so richtig was dazu gefunden. Kannst du mir bitte etwas auf die Sprünge helfen? Sorry, ich habe erst gerade vor 2 Tagen mit meinen ersten Versuchen angefangen, weiss noch nicht so auf anhieb was wohin kommt. 

Comment: @TimeToLearn du kannst einfach auf Github danach suchen. Lies dir auch nochmal https://discord.js.org/ durch c: